# SELECT from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

My tables:

table1

```
id|name_transfer|id_account_from|value_from|id_account_to|value_to
------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |transfer1    |1              |1000      |2            |1000
```

table2

```
id|name_account|
----------------
1 |account1    |
2 |account2    |
```

How write the query, that I gived this:

```
transfer1|account1|1000|account2|1000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
  t1.name_transfer, 
  t2a.name_account as name_account_from, 
  t1.value_from, 
  t2b.name_account as  name_account_to, 
  t1.value_to
from
  table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2a on t2a.id = t1.id_account_from
  inner join table2 t2b on t2b.id = t1.id_account_to
where
  t1.id = 1
```

Comment: And how implement in SELECT "WHERE t1.id=1" ?

Comment: from (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=1) AS t1

Comment: Better add a where: `select * from table1 join.. join... where t1.id = 1`. (Added to the example too)